# Create multiple files from a multiple file upload

Tags: vb.net, webforms

I can upload multiple files using FileUpload but when I run my code only ONE new file is created even though multiple are uploaded. So my output is only one file despite multiple being successfully uploaded.

Any help with how to fix this would be great. thanks in advance.

```
<asp:FileUpload ID="FileUpload1" runat="server" AllowMultiple="true" />
<asp:Button ID="Button1" Text="Upload File" runat="server" OnClick="UploadFile" />

'--Upload Multiple Files
    Dim fileName As String = Path.GetFileName(FileUpload1.PostedFile.FileName)
    Dim filePath As String = Server.MapPath("~/Files/") & fileName
    FileUpload1.SaveAs(filePath)


    For Each postedFile As HttpPostedFile In FileUpload1.PostedFiles


       '-- Create new file to output
        Dim NewFile As String = filePath & "_NewCreatedFile.txt"
        Dim FilWtr As New StreamWriter(NewFile)


        '-- close file
        FilWtr.Close()

    Next
```

Comment: Should you be using the StreamWriter constructor that takes a boolean for whether to overwrite existing file or create new?  https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.streamwriter.-ctor?view=net-7.0#system-io-streamwriter-ctor(system-string-system-boolean)

Comment: ...or just use a new name for each file?

Comment: You're using a constant file name on each iteration of the loop.  Can't help but think seen this exact question a few weeks back where the exact same comments were given.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you allow multiple files, then the upload control does return a "collection of those files.

This should work:

```
    For Each postedFile As HttpPostedFile In FileUpload1.PostedFiles

        Dim fileName As String = Path.GetFileName(postedFile.FileName)
        Dim filePath As String = Server.MapPath("~/Files/") & fileName

        FileUpload1.SaveAs(filePath)

    Next
```